# Why are the seven thunders of Rev.10:4 sealed and what was their message?

Tags: revelation, eschatology

When you say this is opinionated you will be right. Rev.10:4 has been previously discussed and that is also true, but no conclusion was reached. Some of the previous discussion had great merit. I think we all can agree that the seven thunders eminate from very close to God's throne. The question I wish to consider by more heads than just mine is this:why is only this one thing sealed when John is told in Rev.22:10 ...Seal not the sayings of the prophecy of this book....I may have an answer of what but not when is sealed in the seven thunders but I have been told this is not a forum and will only test the waters on this before going further.

Comment: The fact that they are sealed means that we cannot know!

Comment: That was the purpose of the question. Everything in Revelation except this was commanded to NOT be sealed. Documentation is Rev.22:10.

Comment: Correct - and because this was sealed, it is NOT revealed.  Further, John is told NOT to write down the messages of the seven thunders.  End of story!!

Comment: I actually don't see how it was sealed. If John did not write it down, he could not seal it up?  Moreover, this secret was only temporary. An angel immediately says that the mystery will be revealed when the seventh angel blows his horn, which actually happens in ch. 11. See my answer to learn the mystery ;-)

Comment: You mention that this subject of the "7 Thunders" was previously discussed. Were you referring to my Q. 87926 of just 3 days ago, where I suggested that the "7 Bowls of God's wrath" may in fact be what the "7 Thunders" are all about?? If so, why not comment on that, or better still give an answer to same? It would seem that you have ignored my Q. and basically asked the same Q. but in a different way. Regardless of whether you were referencing my Q. or not,  I now move to also "Close" your Q, for being, to all intents and purposes, a duplication.

Comment: I meant Q.87924.

Comment: @ Olde English My question went far beyond your question of just associating the 7 thunders with the 7 th Trump which also includes the seven vials. My post if you read it and all comments closely attempted to suggest what the seven thunders were addressing and why they had to be sealed. I posted a new question for this reason. I am not familiar enough with this sites protocols on overlapping topics. Feel free to share your longer experience on this site.

Comment: @ Olde English your question was roughly could the 7 thunders be connected to the 7th Trump and 7 vials. Could was the operative word and since we don't know for sure what the 7 thunders are exactly it could, but the insinuation that I copied your question is totally false. Will you lay claim to every other event in Revelation because in many senses they are all connected by the term Revelation. You should have let both questions play out on their on merits, then you would have seen my question was totally different except for the 7 thunders being a subject in both.

Comment: *Will you lay claim to every other event in Revelation because in many senses they are all connected by the term Revelation.* That's being a little bit ridiculous for you to say that. Your enquiry was with regard to the "7 Thunders" and the message within, which is exactly what my Q. was about. I was the one who went further into that, the *sealing* being only temporary after all, you merely scratched the surface.

Comment: Your argument that the sealing of the seven thunders was temporary is speculative at best. If what you say is true then tell us what the seven thunders uttered when the temporary sealing ran out. Then tell us what purpose was served by God sealing this one thing in the whole book of Revelation. Please document with scripture.

Comment: I was the one *asking* the question, in the hope that I could get a good answer. I merely hinted as to what the "Thunders" might represent. We know from **Rev, 10:7** that the *mystery* of God is finished when the 7th angel blows/sounds his trumpet, but further prophesying needed to be done before the unsealing, see **Rev, 10:11**. To my mind, if the *mystery* of God is to be *finished* at the 7th trumpet blast and the 7th trumpet incorporates the "7 Bowls" of God's (final) wrath, then it's all just **elementary**. We are being asked to go into a "chat" room, but I'm done, for now at least.

Answer (score 1):

Since only one person has responded to this question and voiced an opinion (it cannot and should not be dealt with) I will tell you what my analyzing of the total prophetic scriptures suggest. The one and only thing Jesus said in Mathew 24 and Mark 13 that he didn't know was the hour or the day of his 2nd coming. Scripture tells us in the same chapters referenced above (specifically Mt.24:14 and Mrk.13:10) that when the Gospel is preached and published to all the world and witnessed to all nations, THEN THE END SHALL COME. I submit to you this end is the WHEN of Jesus' 2nd coming. and also when time shall be no longer as quoted in Rev.10:6. If you believe like I do that the volume of the book, the Bible, proves itself then the last thing I will suggest is that what the seven thunders uttered (Might,Might,Might) have been and then was sealed: the time of the 2nd coming which is when the 7th Trump sounds. This is my opinion !!! . Know for sure that I set no date. Also tell me why God put this in his Word if He didn't have some reason. God is not the author of confusion. I study diligently. This offered not to mislead anybody but to stimulate thought on what MIGHT be.

Comment: Before you get angry with me look at the context . The 7th Trump is about to sound. The kingdoms of this world become the kingdoms of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ. I think this worthy of a time change.

Comment: Welcome to BH.se RHP. I'm normally a defender of "opinion-based" questions. But here you've kind of thrown the rule into our faces.  Also, I wish you would have waited a while before writing your own answer. You answer makes it seems you weren't actually looking for an answer but already had one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Dan. I must admit all the rules I have yet to master, but I have only been aware of this site a few days. I followed a link on the He in 2nd Th.2. Never have understood how you pull the Holy Spirit out of that whole chapter. It seems like the new translations are imposing their preconceived doctrines and making void the original translations.

Comment: I'm lost as to what you mean regrading the He in 2 Th.2.   Yes, some new translation do play fast and loose with the text, but some older translations are not aware of modern findings comparing various manuscript variations, Hebrew vs Greek OT etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Revelation 10:4

> And when the seven thunders spoke, I was about to write,
> but I heard a voice from heaven, saying, “Seal up what the seven
> thunders said, and do not write it down!”

John was ordered not to write down what the thunders said but immediately an angel declares that the mystery will be revealed after the seventh angel blows his horn. As I read it, we do get a major hint as to what the thunders said:

> Revelation 10:5-7
>
> 5 Then the angel that I had seen standing on the sea and on the land raised his right hand to heaven. 6 He swore... "There will no longer be a delay, but in the days when the seventh angel will blow his trumpet, then the
> mystery of God will be completed, as he announced to his servants the
> prophets.”
>
> Revelation 11:15
>
> The seventh angel blew his trumpet, and there were loud voices in
> heaven saying, 'The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our
> Lord and of his Christ, and he will reign forever and ever.'

After this, 24 elders recite a hymn of praise and then:

> Then the temple of God in heaven was opened, and the ark of his
> covenant appeared in his temple. There were flashes of lightning,
> rumblings and peals of thunder, an earthquake, and severe hail.

Whether the above events are a complete description of what the "seven thunders" said or not is unclear. However, immediately after John does not write down the message of the thunders, an angel declares that the "mystery of God" is to be completed when the seventh angel blows his trumpet. In chapter 11 that actually happens. The seventh angel blows, and we learn at least part of the mystery: Loud voices declare that "the kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our
Lord and of his Christ." Associated with this we read of flashes of lightning, rumblings and peals of thunder as the Temple (in heaven) is opened an the Ark is revealed. It seems the "loud voices" of 11:15 have finally revealed the mystery that was not written down in 10:4.

**Conclusion**: although what the seven thunders say is temporarily sealed (not written down), it appears that in chapter 11 we learn at least one important part of what they said: "the kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of his Christ."

Comment: Thanks @Dan we are thinking in a similar vane. I flashed on something in your post. The fact that the ark is now again mentioned. Given what the ark represented in the OLD Testament someone should ask why it has now reappeared. You should have first honors on that. I think it would be a great question.

Comment: Revelation is a pretty Jewish text IMO... or at least Jewish-Christian. Note also that the ark  is in the "temple of God in heaven", and depending on when one dates Revelation, the earthly temple may have still stood as well. The Christians of Acts 21 still attended it.  BTW my username is @Dan Fefferman... plain old Dan tags someone else.

Comment: @ Dan Fefferman Correct me if I am wrong but you see what the 7 thunders saying as the events coming after the 7th trump. I see what the 7 thunders uttered as the day and hour or when the 7th Trump sounds. Very different in my opinion but if on a witness stand I would definitely agree they are associated.I also see the mystery of God as all previous prophecy in the Bible. Ref.Ch10:7 " as he hath declared to his servants the prophets" . This also should be tempered with "that there should be time no longer". We are talking about the end of the world (aion)  age my friend.

Comment: @ Dan Fefferman I ran out of space. The last remark ties with Jesus' words in the Olivet Prophecy of MT.24 & Mk 13. The way I teach prophecy what Jesus, Paul, John and Peter taught on the second coming agrees. I think that you and many others on this site see an escatology similar to mine. We will see.